# Google Sheets. Script. Delete values based on cell value, then reorganize back again

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm not a master in scripting, I've mixed a little bit of code from here and there, and came up with a very neat code to clear all rows based on another cell value, and then reorganize them to be in order without leaving a blank row.

The problem is, the code gets values since the first row, which has formulas in it, that I would like to protect.

Can you help me please get past this issue?

I want the code to work from the row 6 and forward.

```
// Deleting Rows Based on Cell Values

//GLOBALS

var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var SHEET = SS.getSheetByName("Assignments");
var RANGE = SHEET.getRange("A:F");


var DELETE_VAL = "Delivered";
var COL_TO_SEARCH = 5; //Zero is first

function main() {

  var startTime = new Date().getTime();

  var deleteSelectedRows = removeThenSetNewVals();

  var runTime = (new Date().getTime() - startTime)/1000;
  Logger.log("Runtime is: "+runTime + " seconds");
};

function removeThenSetNewVals(){

  var rangeVals = RANGE.getValues();

  var newRangeVals = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < rangeVals.length; i++){
    if(rangeVals[i][COL_TO_SEARCH] != DELETE_VAL){

      newRangeVals.push(rangeVals[i]);
    };
  };

  RANGE.clearContent();

  var newRange = SHEET.getRange(1,1,newRangeVals.length, newRangeVals[0].length);
  newRange.setValues(newRangeVals);
};
```

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I comented the `RANGE.clearContent` as you were cleaning the entire Range from A to F. I added an else condition with a clear only for the row with "Delivered"

```
function removeThenSetNewVals(){

      var rangeVals = RANGE.getValues();

      var newRangeVals = [];

      for(var i = 0; i < rangeVals.length; i++){
        if(rangeVals[i][COL_TO_SEARCH] != DELETE_VAL){
          newRangeVals.push(rangeVals[i]);

        } else {
          Logger.log("clear row" + (i+1));
          SHEET.getRange("C"+(i+1)+":F"+(i+1)).clearContent(); 

        }
      };

     //* RANGE.clearContent();

      var newRange = SHEET.getRange(1,1,newRangeVals.length, newRangeVals[0].length);
      newRange.setValues(newRangeVals);
    };
```

Comment: I tried that before, it didn't work. The script makes that when you push the new values, it goes from the row 1. So all the values that are not "delivered" will be pushed from the row 1. Tricky thing, I think I need to change that, and some other variable in the last lines of the code, to push the new values only after the 6th line also :-(

Comment: I see, can you share an example of your sheet?

Comment: Of course! Sorry for the delay. But how can I do that? Let me try: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BCzJbYnSqDExQLYDpRRcW6PjmJc3fj7vjymLtRIdPoE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your issue, I updated my answer.

Comment: That's weird... you see, there's a =today() formula in F2, and after I push the script, that formula is erased... what could be the issue? Well, I could move over to the H column of course. But I'm really intrigued about why this is happening, if you would be kind enough to help me with this I'll be glad! I'm trying to learn a little bit of scripting myself and it's very challenging...

Comment: It's probably because of getRange("A:F"), as it's taking all the cells from A1 to the last F. Then the [clearContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent) removes the "content" of the cells, in this case the formula. If my answer was useful to you, please accept it so others can see it works without reading the comments :)